# Clickable list items with two fields: a serial number and a name

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list of names organized into a  element. List elements now purely consist of names, e.g. Agnes, Billy, Bob. Each of them are clickable. Example code (also available [at this link](http://jsfiddle.net/avfc59oy/10/)):

```css
#myList {
  width: 50vw;
  margin:1vw;
  background:#666;  
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 0.75vw 0.75vw 0.75vw 0.75vw; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: calc(12px + 0.2vw); 
  color: black; 
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee; 
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <ul id="myUL">
    <!-- <li>
        <a href="#">
          <a href="#" class="serial_num">1</a>
          <a href="#" class="indicator_name">Adele</a>
        </a>
      </li> -->
    <li><a href="#" class="serial_num">1</a><a href="#" class="name">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eleanor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Erica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Freddie</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I would like to improve design in such a way that each list item have a serial number (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.) in a separate box in the same line. A picture is worth a thousand words, so here is what I am planning to create:

[image]

Importantly, I don't want to logically separate the serial number from the name itself, as these are still to be treated as one unit and hence they must be clickable together. For example replacing this:

```
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
```

by this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="serial_num">1</a><a href="#" class="name">Agnes</a></li>
```

is incorrect, as the `<a>` tag for the number "1" and the `<a>` tag for the name "Agnes" are no longer related, no longer clickable together.

Hence, my idea was to keep the `<a>` tags and create two `<div>`s within like so:

```
<li><a href="#"><div class="serial_num">1</div><div class="name">Agnes</div></a></li>
```

Now I believe I'm not far from the intended result, yet I didn't manage to figure it out. I assume the `display` property is among the ones to tinker with here, but I didn't succeed.

Full example of my current output can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avfc59oy/74/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're going for

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 5px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a .serial_num, a .name {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

a .serial_num {
  border-right: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="serial_num">1</div>
    <div class="name">Agnes</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox:

```css
#myList {
  width: 50vw;
  background: #666;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myUL li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#myUL li:last-of-type a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.name {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.serial_num {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.serial_num,
.name {
  padding: .75rem;
}

#myUL li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">1</span><span class="name">Agnes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">2</span><span class="name">Agnes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">3</span><span class="name">Agnes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">4</span><span class="name">Agnes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">5</span><span class="name">Agnes</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. However dropping the display attribuite causes row elements not to fill in the entire row any more. That's why I originally added that attribute and started tinkering with it. Is there perhaps a solution for `name` to automatically fill in the entire row, alongside the fixed size of `serial_num`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display: inline-block;`

```
.serial_num {
  width: 5%;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
.name {
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Rojo. However, when doing so, both the `serial_num` and the `name` elements shrink to the size of their content instead of the two together properly filling up the entire line. Maybe I wasn't entirely clear about this in my post. Is there an easy way to tell `name` to be in the same line but fill up the entire space available in that row? I know that with an inline-block it is possible to specify height and width but I feel an automatic fill solution would be more elegant than hardcoding dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the `a` tag with span tags between and then style each column **name** **serial_num** individually to suit your needs.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myList {
  width: 45vw; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myUL li a {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: calc(12px + 0.2vw); 
  color: black; 
  display: flex;
}

#myUL li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee; 
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
}

.serial_num {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 15%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: calc(12px + 0.3em);
}

.serial_num, .name{  
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.75vw 0.75vw 0.75vw 0.75vw; 
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#"><div class="serial_num">1</div><div class="name">Agnes</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">55</span><span class="name">Billy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">188</span><span class="name">Bob</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">255</span><span class="name">Calvin</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">260</span><span class="name">Dan</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">360</span><span class="name">Eleanor</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">555</span><span class="name">Erica</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="serial_num">1000</span><span class="name">Freddie</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is your fiddle updated: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yq5jtc4/)